# glfwSetKeyCallback() from GLFW is not called constantly during a key press

Tags: c++, opengl, keyboard, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to make my game do something when I press a key. I'm using GLFW to handle Windows API for me. I got stuck and confused when I used the mention callback function in title.

Referenced doc: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#input_keyboard

I followed "Key input" resources (not "Text input"), but I get a kinda text input callback curve, like, when I keep pressed a key, I get pressed key event, then it stops for some time, and then I get repeated events. Shouldn't callbacks be constant in time (without that time gap)? This is my code:

```
void onKeyPress(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && action != GLFW_RELEASE)
    {
        camera.pos += glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        updateCameraMatrices();
    }
}

// ...

glfwSetKeyCallback(window, onKeyPress);
```

Comment: In GLFW key event may have following actions: `GLFW_PRESS`, `GLFW_RELEASE` or `GLFW_REPEAT`. So by filtering on the `action != GLFW_RELEASE` condition you effectively getting `GLFW_PRESS` and `GLFW_REPEAT` events. Try changing the condition to `action == GLFW_PRESS` and you should get the event only once, when the key is pressed.

Comment: @VVV, I don't intend to get this result. I want to get events like these from GLFW_REPEAT, from the time I get GLFW_PRESS, I want continuously events.

Answer (score 3):

Nvm. It seems like my expectations were wrong. I should just listen for GLFW_PRESS and GLFW_RELEASE, store the key status, and use if(status) in my main loop.

Comment: What you get on windows is the exact behaviour you get if you open notepad and hold a key down :- the repeat behaviour is more tuned to provide a "good" experience to someone wanting to type lots of symbols in a document. Game engines usually need up/down notifications, or, for devices like joysticks and pressure sensitive buttons, they simply poll the device per frame.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use event callbacks at all if you just want to know wether a key is pressed or not. Just use `glfwGetKey(window,key)` to get the current key status (this returns `GLFW_PRESS` or `GLFW_RELEASE`). See [here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#input_key) for more details.